# Retrive user meta for If/Else statement wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to retrieve user meta (Billing country) for a custom email template to do an If/Else statement to show fields based on user set country.

Whats the best approach here?

Code to clarify what I want to do, that is not working:

```
$countries_obj = new WC_Countries();
$country = $countries_obj->get_countries();

    if($country == 'NL' || $country == 'BE'){
           echo '<p style="margin: 0 0 10px;">'; 
    echo  $email_text;
    echo  '</p>';   
   
    }elseif($country == 'DE' || $country == 'AT'){
            echo '<p style="margin: 0 0 10px;">'; 
    echo  $email_text_de;
    echo  '</p>';       
        
    }else{
          echo '<p style="margin: 0 0 10px;">'; 
    echo  $email_text_en;
    echo  '</p>';   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That actually looks a job for translation if it's just a matter of some translated text. Worpdress has a series of native functions to make the file translation-ready.

You can read more about that here: https://themes.artbees.net/blog/translation-ready-themes/ but there are A LOT of sources online to understand what you should do.

After that you should make your website multi-language by installing, configuring and translating all the parts you need.
There are a bunch of translations plugin for wp, the biggest and most famous one is WPML i guess

Comment: The site is translated for most part by WeGlot. For the registration mail Im using ACF to load text in Theme settings in different languages these ACF field I want to display depending on the users billing country.